# How to minimise the trace of a positive Matrix over all permutation of columns

Tags: python, matrix, optimization, linear-algebra

I have a 10x10 **positive symmetric matrix**, I need to find the optimal permutation of the columns in order to **minimise the trace**. I can't try all permutations because that would be a 10! problem. Any ideas on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Only permutate the columns (losing symmetry)?

Comment: minimize the trace without loosing positive symmetry or just minimize? Also what is this question marked Python? Do you have an algorithm?

Comment: Does the resulting matrix also need to be positive symmetric? Do you have any reason to believe that the form of the original matrix could allow a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: The original matrix is symmetric but I don't need to maintain the symmetry. 

I am doing this using python, it's part of a bigger code @RoryDaulton

Comment: Actually there's an answer already!
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2876711/maximize-the-trace-of-a-matrix-by-permuting-its-rows?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can consider it to be a case of assigning workers to tasks, where you have an equal number of workers and tasks. The problem is to assign exactly one worker to each task.

A worker is a column. A task is to stay in a certain position in the matrix. The cost is the element of that column that falls under the diagonal of the matrix.

You can read more on the problem here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem, one solution is using the Hungarian algorithm (also mention in the answer linked to by JNYC in the comments). Implementations of it are available in many languages.

Comment: Yes JNYC was me! Thank you in any case!

Comment: Yes I’ve noticed sometime after I posted the answer haha. Actually started typing it before I’ve seen the comment at all.